# upload the recorded audio to mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, blob

I'm trying to upload the recorded audio to mongodb by converting blob into file. it is successfully uploaded but whenever i am trying to use that upload url in show like [object object]. my code is given below

```
 onStop = (audioData) => {
    const file = new File([audioData], "audiofile.mp3" , {type: "audio/wav/ogg", lastModified: Date.now()});
    this.props.setFile(file);
  
   
  }
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getImage = async () => {
            if(file){
                const data = new FormData();
                data.append("name", file.name);
                data.append("file", file);
                let response = await uploadFile(data);
                setImage(response.data);
            }
        }
        getImage();
    }, [file])

<Audio setFile={setFile}/>
```